# Pass an uninitialized struct value to itself in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

How is this allowed to compile? I'm passing an uninitialized value of a struct to itself:

```c
typedef struct test {
  int a;
} test;

int main(){
   test t= {t.a};
   return 0;
}
```

Same can be done in C++ using constructors and references:

```cpp
class test{
 public:
 test(const test& input) : a(input.a){}
 int a;
};

int main(){
  test t(t);
  return 0;
}
```

Will this cause undefined behaviour?

### Edit

What if this the value was initialized, would that make a difference?
How can `t.a` get used in this expression `test t= {t.a};` if `t` isn't even fully defined yet?

Comment: Yes, trying to read an uninitialized variable is UB.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with this? What value do you want `t.a` to be after that code?

Comment: Sorry added a second question in an edit.

Comment: The edit doesn't make sense.

Comment: It seems to me like a typical chicken and egg problem. How would it be initialized it it's a part of struct that is just being initialized.

Comment: How about now? I'm just asking how can you use `t.a` if `t` isn't even fully defined yet?

Comment: @ S. Kaczor correct, how this compiling? is `t` technically fully defined at that point?

Comment: `t` is defined, and that's all the compiler needs to use it in an expression. Likely the amount of code needed by a compiler to prevent idiocy like `int x = x;` isn't worth the effort to make it flat out illegal, but if you crank up the optimizer and turn on a reasonable number of optional warnings, the compiler will let you kow you're making a boo boo.. Eg: https://godbolt.org/z/qqr8MPP9h

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 2 answers.

One is based on common sense: is there any reasonable behavior that could be expected for such code? I can't think of any...

One is fact based: read of uninitialized variable is an UB.

Comment: Sorry added a second question in an edit.